# How to create a helper that can be access to its function name

Tags: php, codeigniter

This my library filename: MY_is_date_helper.php

```
function is_date($date){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('Y-m-d') == $date;
}
```

My question is how can I call it to my MVC using just like this:

```
is_date('2000-01-01');
```

like what the `base_url()` did without creating any file at the system folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save file in **application/helpers** dir

Then you need to load your helper in controller like

```
$this->load->helper('MY_is_date_helper');
```

Or add it to autoload in config

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('MY_is_date_helper');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your current php file where you want to use finction -

```
<?php
    include 'MY_is_date_helper.php';

    is_date('2000-01-01'); // call function
?>
```

Comment: I think this will not work because I'm using codeigniter framework